# Room with computer racks, with or without ventilation

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, airflow, heat-treatment

I have a room of computer rack that with 2750 watt power needs, which according to [this site](https://www.enviromon.net/advanced-server-btu-calculator/), I need 9000 BTU/h AC. I'm deciding if I should put a vent in the room or not. When there's a ventilation, it will look like this:
[image: Scenario 1]
Note that there are two wind turbine ventilators on the roof. Also the attic is cool because of the good air circulation.
Question for this scenario:
1. Will the AC and the grill vent vanquish the humidity from the air outside, which is warm and humid?
2. Will dust enter the room via vent despite the fact that the airflow is upward to the wind turbine ventilator?
3. Is 9000 BTU an optimum number? Is it too much or too little? I'm thinking most of the heat is drawn to the vent.

The second scenario will look like this:
[image: Second scenario]
In this scenario, instead of a ventilation with a chimney, there is a ducting that caries heat, which escapes to the attic and goes to the wind turbine vents. Question:
Will this give faster heat reduction whereas there is no way humid air will come to the room?

regards

Comment: Better on the DIY stack exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, switch rooms and IT rooms tend to just recirculate the room volume with some small DX cooling. It is not viewed as an occupied space, hence no need for extract for heat rejection, you would need some provision for smoke extract though.

Also another design consideration, exposing an IT space to external environment is not a good idea if you are likely to get high/very low RH.

Thats my 5 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Don't vent the cool dry air to the atmosphere.  That is just wasting energy.

Don't have a single cool air input with a seprate distribution duct.

Have a cool air source with 1 or more ducts into the room (like your house).

Most computer rooms use the sub-floor to distribute the cool dry air.